# Show on-the-fly PDF (Content-type:application/pdf) in Laravel Blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created the DHL label creation script in Laravel and get the generated PDF, in the Controller. The "$image" is created based on the user input and supplied by DHL API as on the fly. In general (in normal PHP script, not in Laravel), we do the following to show the PDF as I see this is working fine:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename=label_123demo.pdf");
echo $image;
```

So, in the controller  file, I have written the code as below:

```
$data['image'] = $image; // generated image from DHL API
return view('Administrator.shipments.dhl-post', $data);
```

And in the Blade file, I wrote the following:

```
<div style="border: 2px solid #B0AFBE; width:800px;">
@php
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:inline;filename=label_123demo.pdf");
echo $image; 
@endphp
</div>
```

But it shows nothing.

The DHL Label creation script is below:

```
$message_ref = '';
            for ($i=0; $i< 30; $i++)
            {
                $message_ref .= rand(0, 9);

            }   
            $message_time = date("Y-m-d") . "T" . date("H:i:sP");
            $ab_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day")); 

$query =<<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>\n
<req:ShipmentValidateRequest xmlns:req="http://www.dhl.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com ship-val-req.xsd">\n
<Request>\n
<ServiceHeader>\n
<MessageTime>$message_time</MessageTime>\n
<MessageReference>$message_ref</MessageReference>\n
<SiteID>XXXX</SiteID>\n
<Password>XXXX</Password>\n
</ServiceHeader>\n
</Request>\n
<RequestedPickupTime>N</RequestedPickupTime>\n
<NewShipper>N</NewShipper>\n
<LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>\n
<PiecesEnabled>Y</PiecesEnabled>\n
<Billing>\n
<ShipperAccountNumber>XXXXX</ShipperAccountNumber>\n
<ShippingPaymentType>S</ShippingPaymentType>\n
<BillingAccountNumber>XXXXX</BillingAccountNumber>\n
<DutyPaymentType>R</DutyPaymentType>\n
</Billing>\n
<Consignee>\n
<CompanyName>XYZ</CompanyName>\n
<AddressLine>XXXXXX</AddressLine>\n
<City>Lekki</City>\n
<Division>Lagos</Division>\n
<DivisionCode>LG</DivisionCode>\n
<PostalCode>98981</PostalCode>\n
<CountryCode>NG</CountryCode>\n
<CountryName>Nigeria</CountryName>\n
<Contact>\n
<PersonName>MyName</PersonName>\n
<PhoneNumber>713-530-1160</PhoneNumber>\n
<PhoneExtension></PhoneExtension>\n
</Contact>\n
</Consignee>\n
<Dutiable>\n
<DeclaredValue>200</DeclaredValue>\n
<DeclaredCurrency>USD</DeclaredCurrency>\n
<TermsOfTrade>DAP</TermsOfTrade>\n
</Dutiable>\n
<Reference>\n
<ReferenceID>13</ReferenceID>\n
<ReferenceType>St</ReferenceType>\n
</Reference>\n
<ShipmentDetails>\n
<NumberOfPieces>3</NumberOfPieces>\n
<Pieces><Piece>\n
<PieceID>3</PieceID>\n
<PackageType>EE</PackageType>\n
<Weight>8</Weight>\n
<DimWeight>8</DimWeight>\n
<Width>6</Width>\n
<Height>8</Height>\n
<Depth>8</Depth>\n
<PieceContents></PieceContents>\n
</Piece></Pieces>\n
<Weight>287</Weight>\n
<WeightUnit>L</WeightUnit>\n
<GlobalProductCode>P</GlobalProductCode>\n
<Date>2018-06-27</Date>\n
<Contents>SHIPMENT #13</Contents>\n
<DoorTo>DD</DoorTo>\n
<DimensionUnit>I</DimensionUnit>\n
<PackageType>EE</PackageType>\n
<IsDutiable>N</IsDutiable>\n
<CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>\n
</ShipmentDetails>\n
<Shipper>\n
<ShipperID>XXXXXX</ShipperID>\n
<CompanyName>MyCompany</CompanyName>\n
<RegisteredAccount>XXXXX</RegisteredAccount>\n
<AddressLine>Address XYX demo</AddressLine>\n
<City>Tuscon</City>\n
<Division>Iowa</Division>\n
<DivisionCode>IW</DivisionCode>\n
<PostalCode>50020</PostalCode>\n
<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>\n
<CountryName>United States</CountryName>\n
<Contact>\n
<PersonName>PersonName</PersonName>\n
<PhoneNumber>12345600</PhoneNumber>\n
<PhoneExtension></PhoneExtension>\n
</Contact>\n
</Shipper>\n
<EProcShip>N</EProcShip>\n
<LabelImageFormat>PDF</LabelImageFormat>\n
<RequestArchiveDoc>Y</RequestArchiveDoc>\n
<Label>\n
<LabelTemplate>8X4_thermal</LabelTemplate>\n
<Logo>Y</Logo>\n
<Resolution>200</Resolution>\n
</Label>\n
</req:ShipmentValidateRequest>
EOT;

$url = "https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet?isUTF8Support=true";

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$query");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
preg_match("/<OutputImage>(.*?)<\/OutputImage>/", $output, $matches);
$image = base64_decode($matches[1]);
$data['image'] = $image;
$data['demo'] = "demo.pdf";
return view('Administrator.shipments.dhl-post', $data);
```

Comment: Use Laravel :) not `header()`. `return response()->file(path/to/file, ['Content-disposition' => 'inline; filename=FILENAME.pdf]))`; Also use http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ not raw `curl`.

Comment: @Kyslik The PDF is generating on the  fly and nothing is stored in to storage. Can you give your answer based on this. The scenario is when I submit the details, the PDF will be supplied by DHL and I need to show the same in blade.

Comment: Use `php://temp` or `php://memory` descriptor to store the file first, or use streams not sure how Laravel handles those since I did not need to use them - Guzzle supports streams and I bet `response()->stream(..)` exists.

Comment: @Kyslik can you post your answer with more explanation?

Comment: So can you generate real PDF from whatever you have and store it on disk? I bet your **creation script** does not work the way you expect it to.

Comment: @Kyslik creation script working fine. As my question, I said that in normal PHP (not in laravel), it works fine. I need to show the PDF in laravel within the blade viw.

Comment: header() is used to send raw http headers, not to stream a file.  You can't use it inside a div (or blade, or any html).  As suggested above, use a temp file or stream.  You can't use both a header format, and blade.  It doesn't work like that

Comment: @GoatHater - Can you please post your answer with a bit explanation?

Comment: @Kyslik you are missing a ' on your code

Comment: @Kyslik I would delete and comment again or add as answer if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of php's header function is slightly off.

[Link to php header manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> header() is used to send a raw HTTP header. See the » HTTP/1.1
>   specification for more information on HTTP headers.
>
> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

You should either temp save the file, use a stream, or link it from another page/route

[PHP Temp File Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php)

Since this doesn't answer the question, merely points out an incorrect use of header() I didn't want to post as answer, but did so by request

Comment: Thanks! I've created the PDF in public folder and show the same through embed src. This could be an easy solution for me.